# Without converting measures to dimension how to show measure values without aggregation?

Tags: visualization, tableau-api, data-science

I want to show measure values in 'measure' not as a dimension without aggregation

Comment: Any specific reason behind why you don't want to convert it into a dimension?

Comment: You would find the following link useful:
https://community.tableau.com/thread/261766